# unicode error preventing creation of text file

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

> (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I have also tried reading different files in the same directory an get this same unicode error as well.

```
file1 = open("C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\newtextdocument.txt", "w")
for i in range(1000000):
    file1.write(str(i) + "\n")
```

Comment: Show us the code that's running when the error happens.

Comment: It is the second image http://imgur.com/XKhJQzL,w78ZAGg#1

Comment: Please put the actual error and code in the question instead of links to images.  Links may not be valid in the future and it is easier for someone to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should escape backslashes inside the string literal. Compare:

```
>>> print("\U00000023")  # single character
#
>>> print(r"\U00000023") # raw-string literal with 
\U00000023
>>> print("\\U00000023") # 10 characters
\U00000023

>>> print("a\nb")  # three characters (literal newline)
a
b
>>> print(r"a\nb") # four characters (note: `r""` prefix)
a\nb
```

Answer (score 1):

`\U` is being treated as the start of a Unicode literal.  Use a raw string (a preceding `r`) to prevent this translation:

```
>>> 'C:\Users'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>>> r'C:\Users'
'C:\\Users'
```